# What is the practice of conforming to group standards in society called?

Tags: word-choice

Japanese society highly values the group over the individual. I am unable to find a name for this practice. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa_(Japanese_culture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人より集団を重んじる
集団主義 (as opposed to 個人主義)
協調性
調和の精神
和の精神
和を以て貴しとなす

... maybe?